# Lots of reads being spent in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I opened two instances of my app in browser. In 1st increase I was creating company name. In 2nd instance, a dropdown of companies was being opened. As soon as I add a new company, in the 2nd tab, it instantly calls all of the list again and it is costing me reads.

For example if there were 20 companies already downloaded, and if new company is added, it is loading 21 causing me 21 reads. **Instead it should load only the new one.**

Code being used on `ngOnInit` to fetch **company list**:

```
    //start fetch
    this.crudService.read_guardcompany().subscribe(data => {
      this.bucketlist = data.map(e => {
        return {
          name: e.payload.doc.data()['companyname'],
          docid: e.payload.doc.id,
        };
      })
      console.log(this.bucketlist);
    });//end fetch
```

**crud.service** code

```
  read_guardcompany() {
    return this.firestore.collection('guardscompanies').snapshotChanges();
  }
```

How do I control this, so that it only loads the new item and not all again?

Attaching images for more clarity:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By going through the firebase documentation here [1], I have found some important information about the read operation. Seems like might be helpful for you to understand what should count towards read operations. Also this public blog [2] describes how to reduce the number of read operations in firestore which might be helpful in your case. Additionally you can check this [3] documentation might give more insights about reading data in firestore.

[1] https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#listens

[2] https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-reduce-the-number-of-read-operations-in-cloud-firestore-9f9d6f5a271

[3] https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data